# MongoDB find city

Tags: mongodb

I'm very new to mongoDB and trying to figure out a query for an assignment. I want to find all states for a given city name.

i have a file from here 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/
where the model is listed

i tried doing

```
aggregate({$group : { _id: $"state"}} , {$match : {city : "BOSTON"}});
```

any hints as to why this does not work?

Comment: do you get an error when you execute it?

Comment: Shouldn't the $ be inside the quotes for the state?

Comment: And the `$match` needs to go before the `$group`.

Comment: thanks i did have "$state" that was just a typo but switching the order fixed it thank you! could you explain why it won't work with group before match?

Comment: It's because after the `$group`, all the docs in the pipeline only have an `_id` field so there's no `city` field to match against.

Comment: if you don't mind i'd like to ask you another quick question. i have this query 
db.zips.distinct("state", db.zips.aggregate([ {$group:{_id:{city:"$city"},numberOfzipcodes:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{numberOfzipcodes:-1}}]))
I'm trying to find cities for each state with most zip codes. I don't get an error, but I get an empty set

Comment: you should ask that in a separate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer is that you do not need aggregation to select states having the specified city.

```
db.zipcodes.distinct('state', { city : 'BOSTON' })
```

Concerning the performance - `distinct` and `aggregate` seem to be performing almost the same:

> { "ts" : ISODate("2013-05-04T06:52:02.772Z"), "op" : "command", "ns" :
>   "test.$cmd", "command" : { "aggregate" : "zipcodes", "pipeline" : [   {
>     "$match" : {    "city" : "BELMONT" } },     {   "$group" : {    "_id" : {
>     "state" : "$state" } } } ] }, "ntoreturn" : 1, "keyUpdates" : 0,
>   "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" :
>   NumberLong(13990), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
>   "r" : NumberLong(10), "w" : NumberLong(5) } }, "responseLength" : 436,
>   "millis" : 14, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }

vs

> { "ts" : ISODate("2013-05-04T06:52:11.169Z"), "op" : "command", "ns" :
>   "test.$cmd", "command" : { "distinct" : "zipcodes", "key" : "state",
>   "query" : { "city" : "BELMONT" } }, "ntoreturn" : 1, "keyUpdates" : 0,
>   "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" :
>   NumberLong(12153), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
>   "r" : NumberLong(4), "w" : NumberLong(5) } }, "responseLength" : 262,
>   "millis" : 12, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }

Comment: how did you get a .explain() for an aggregate? because they don't exists .

Comment: they don't exist for distinct either, I get these from profiling `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` then run queries then `db.system.profile.find()`

Comment: but that's pretty useless since we don't have execution plan

Comment: wanna start a chat, seems like you now about mongo, and i would love to ask some questions.

Comment: sorry but I don't really know mongo :) just researching

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it with the aggregation framework: 
"zips" should be your collection.

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$match:
        {
            city: "BOSTON"
        }
    },
    {$group:
        {
            _id: {state: "$state"}
        }
    }
])
```